# Jacoco integration test of API code coverage

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Does Jacoco provide code coverage for integration tests of APIs? That is, I have an instance of my application running locally and I have integration tests where I hit an api offered by my running application instance. In this scenario can I use Jacoco to get how many lines of my running application instance was covered when integration tests where ran?

I have already tried Jacoco's maven plugin's prepare-agent-integration and report-integration goals. But they give code coverage as 0. I think its because jacoco only measures code coverage of the currently ran instance and not the instance whose api is hit.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgot to run the javaagent while running the service. Running the jar file with javaagent with output=tcpserver and then dumping the execution file using Jacoco:dump and creating report using Jacoco:report solved the issue.

`java -javaagent:<path_to_agent>/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=output=tcpserver,address=127.0.0.1 -jar myapp.jar`

`mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests`

`mvn jacoco:report -DdataFile=./target/jacoco.exec`

`mvn jacoco:dump -Djacoco.address=localhost -Djacoco.destFile=./service/target/jacoco.exec`